# Error cause by dependency of a dependency

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When working on Angular Universal app I get the following error:

```bash
preact/compat:211:70-71 - Error: export '_unmount' (imported as 'm') was not found in 'preact' (possible exports: Component, Fragment, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createRef, h, hydrate, isValidElement, options, render, toChildArray)

preact/compat:211:313-314 - Error: export '_unmount' (imported as 'm') was not found in 'preact' (possible exports: Component, Fragment, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createRef, h, hydrate, isValidElement, options, render, toChildArray)

preact/compat:212:44-45 - Error: export '_unmount' (imported as 'm') was not found in 'preact' (possible exports: Component, Fragment, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createRef, h, hydrate, isValidElement, options, render, toChildArray)
```

The error started after I switch projects to work on a Gatsby Preact App,

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` directory, and delete the npm cache with `npm cache clean -f` then run `npm ci --legacy-peer-deps` and the my ssr development build with `npm run dev:ssr` I have also tried to uninstall `preact` and `preact/compat` with `npm uninstall`.

I have also tried printing the local and global packages and did not find preact in them.

The result of npm ls -g --depth=0 is:

```
├── corepack@0.10.0
├── lighthouse@9.6.2
├── npm-check-updates@15.2.1
├── npm@8.11.0
└── typescript@4.7.4
```

I have also checked in the package.json file and did not find any mention of preact.

If I run `npm list preact` i get:

```
├─┬ @walletconnect/web3-provider@1.7.5
│ └─┬ @walletconnect/qrcode-modal@1.7.7
│   └── preact@10.4.1
├─┬ onfido-sdk-ui@8.1.0
│ └── preact@10.9.0
└─┬ walletlink@2.4.0
  └── preact@10.6.4
```